# Full rank matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 401*5677 matrix(say G) and a vector of length 5677 (say Index)
I need to get a full rank (by block) matrix G.

The blocks in my matrix G are defined by the vector Index. For instance, if the first 50 elements of the vector are equal to 1, that means that the first 50 columns of the matrix belong to the group 1 etc.

Do you know how can I get block-wise full rank matrix?? That means, the 401*50 "submatrix" of G must be full rank, and similarly all the rest "submatrices" (each corresponding to a group) must also be full rank.

I'm stucked for too long in that problem! How can I do it in R?

To be more specific, suppose that:

```
G=matrix(c(1,2,2,4,0,2,2,6,1,2,2,4,5,2,2,3,5,2,2,3),nrow=4) 
index=c(1,1,2,2,2)
```

That is, the first two columns of G is group1 and the rest 3 columns is the second group. 
I want to write a code that will do the following:

1. Find the dependent columns in group 1 and make the "submatrix" of G which corresponds to the first group, full rank (e.g if column 1 and 2 are dependent, then only keep one of these)
2. Do the same in the part of G matrix which corresponds to the second group.

So, at the end, the final matrix is full rank within each group (i.e. the part of the final G which corresponds to group 1 is full rank, the part of final G which corresponds to group 2 is also full rank).

I also need to know which columns have been removed(if any) from G in order to remove the corresponding entries from the index vector.

What I'm working with, in order to find an algorihtm to use in the original data is:

```
B=matrix(c(1,2,2,4,0,2,2,6,1,2,2,4,5,2,2,3,5,2,2,3),nrow=4)
s=c(1,1,2,2,2)
unique.s<-unique(s)
k=1
n=nrow(cB)
cB<-cor(B)
for(i in 1:length(unique.s)){
  u=unique.s[i]
  l=length(which(s==u))
  for(r in 1:n){
    for(c in k:k+l-1){
      if(r<c && cB[r,c]==1){
        B[,c]=NA
        s[c]=NA
      }
   }

  }
  k=k+l

}

B.final<-B[,complete.cases(t(B))]
s.final<-s[complete.cases(s)]
```

I try to find dependent columns based on the correlation matrix (I don't now if that's correct). Hence, working on one group of the B matrix every time, I try (with no success), to remove the columns of B depending on whether they have correlation equal to 1 or not. 
For example, if cB[1,2] is 1, then I would like to remove B[,2] column. The procedure is applied once for B[,1:2] which is the B part for the group 1 and once for B[,3:5] which is the part for group 2.

Comment: Maybe construct a small example (using a 5*6 matrix, say), showing what you'd like as output for the given input.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope that helps a little bit :S

Answer (score 1):

### Edited as per comments

**only modification is `Vec[1:nrow(G)]`**

It's a little hard to  tell exactly what you are asking for, but I believe you are looking to subset the matrix based on the unique values in a vector, say `Vec`, where the element index to `Vec` is the row index to `G`.

If that's what you are looking for, then you can iterate over the unique values in Vec

```
 lapply(unique(Vec), function(Ind) G[which(Vec[1:nrow(G)]==Ind), ])  # which is not needed if length(Vec) == nrow(G)
```

Alternatively, you could use by

```
 by(G, Vec[1:nrow(G)], function(x) as.matrix(x, ncol=ncol(G)))
```

Comment: Let me re-write the original question in a slightly different way:
Assume that
G=matrix(c(1,2,2,4,0,2,2,6,1,2,2,4,5,2,2,3,5,2,2,3),nrow=4)
index=c(1,1,2,2,2)

Comment: @DanaiC., please edit the question (instead of posting as comment) since the body of the question allows for more elaborate formatting

Comment: @DanaiC., you simply need to limit `index` to the `nrow(G)`

Comment: That is, the first two columns of G is group1 and the rest 3 columns is the second group.
I want to write a code that will do the following:

1.find the dependent columns in group 1 and make the "submatrix" of G which corresponds to the first group full rank (e.g if column 1 and 2 are dependent, then only keep one of these)
2. Do the same in the part of G matrix which corresponds to the second group.

So, at the end, the final matrix is full rank within each group
I also need to know which columns have been removed from G in order to remove the corresponding entries from the index vector.